# using join with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I am trying to do a join with a case statement.

My query below, what I am trying to do is join based on this condition: "if PROGRAM IS 28 THEN CHECK FOR 2 THINGS
(and t1.DrOfrecord = 'T' or T1.PrimClin = T) IF NOT CHECK FOR ONE (PrimClin = T)"

Attempt #1:

```
SELECT t1.DrOfRecord,  t1.*
FROM FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT AS T0
LEFT OUTER JOIN FD__STAFF_ASSIGNED AS T1 ON T0.OP__DOCID = T1.programAdmitKey
                                         AND T1.DrOfRecord = 'T'
      (case when t0.PgmKey = 28 then OR  t1.PrimClin = 'T' end )
```

Attempt #2:

```
SELECT t1.DrOfRecord, t1.*
FROM FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT AS T0
LEFT OUTER JOIN FD__STAFF_ASSIGNED AS T1 ON T0.OP__DOCID = T1.programAdmitKey 
                                         AND CASE WHEN t0.PgmKey = 28 
                                                      THEN t1.DrOfRecord = 'T' OR t1.PrimClin = 'T' 
                                                      ELSE t1.PrimClin = 'T' 
                                             END
```

Comment: `and t1.PrimClin = 'T' and (t0.PgmKey = 28 and T1.DrOfRecord = 'T' or t0.PgmKey <> 28)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your query is incorrect. You cannot use a case statement inside the ON clause of a join like that.

Here is the correct syntax for the query:

```
SELECT t1.DrOfRecord, t1.*
FROM FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT AS T0
LEFT OUTER JOIN FD__STAFF_ASSIGNED AS T1
ON T0.OP__DOCID = T1.programAdmitKey
AND (T1.PrimClin = 'T' OR (T1.DrOfrecord = 'T' AND T0.PgmKey = 28))
```

If I understand your logic correctly you want all records that satisfy `PrimClin = 'T'` or the two other conditions.

Comment: Thanks! what I want is that if pgmkey = 28 then check for ( PrimClin = T or DrOfRecord = T else (pgmkey <> 28 then just check for PrimClin = 'T'

Comment: I wrote this , would this be OK? Thanks again
 AND (T1.PrimClin = 'T' OR ((T0.PgmKey = 28)) AND (T1.PrimClin = 'T' OR T1.DrOfRecord = 'T'))

Comment: @hubert certainly you can if you want to make the logic more clear, however, since every record that satisfies `PrimClin = 'T'` will be part of the result set you do not need to add it to the alternative in the  `OR (..)` part. And that's why I omitted it. Both queries should give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `CASE WHEN` like:

```sql
SELECT t1.DrOfRecord,  t1.*
FROM  FD__PROGRAM_CLIENT AS T0
LEFT OUTER JOIN FD__STAFF_ASSIGNED AS T1 
  ON (T0.PgmKey = 28 AND (t1.DrOfrecord = 'T' or T1.PrimClin = T) )
     OR (T0.PgmKey <> 28 AND (PrimClin = T) )
```